# Is there a formula for calculating length given pixel density?

Tags: android, ios, geometry

I know you can use various AR packages to do this, but wondering what the formula is to calculate length given a few known values.

For example, let's say my phone is at the same height as a wood dowel, that the dowel rests perpendicular to the phone, and that both the phone and the dowel are parallel to the ground. I know that the phone is exactly 10' away from the dowel and I know the pixel density of my phone is 512. I take a photo. On that photo I then pick one of the ends of the dowel and mark it and determine that it is exactly 1024 pixels from the center. What is the length of the dowel?

There has to be some sort of conversion of pixels to distance but I can't find it.

Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the pixel density you're describing is for your phone's screen, but the measurements you want to take are from a picture taken with your camera. In fact, all the relevant measurements have to be from your camera. You would probably need to know the focal length, and the field of view.

I'm sure that you could come up with the proper formula to calculate it on your specific device, but you wouldn't be able to create a general formula for any device that uses your app. Those AR libraries generally use some markers (or calibration) to figure out the device's camera attributes, and they then use those measurements to calculate everything else.

So, in short, you're better off using the libraries that are made to do this, unless you want to implement all of the calibration in your app

Comment: I found a formula that works with the focal length, etc. Was thinking that there would be a way to avoid knowing that as it isn't discoverable programmatically that I'm aware of, but starting to think you might be right. Still, wondering if the phone could be "calibrated" using a meter stick at a set distance. Might look into that.